# How to mirror and reverse a movement of a canvas object?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

So I have two objects. SquareA and SquareB. SquareA follows the movement of the cursor. Now I want to make SquareB mirror the movement of SquareA but in reverse.

Example:

SquareA goes left, SquareB goes right.
SquareA goes down, SquareB goes up.

I currently have this code to make squareB follow squareA

```
  // update squareA to mouse
  squareA.x = mouseX - (squareB.width * .5);
  squareA.y = mouseY - (squareB.height * .5);

  // update squareB to squareA
  squareB.x = squareA.x;
  squareB.y = squareA.y  - (squareA.height * 2);
```

But I can't think of a way to reverse squareB's movement.

Here's the pen for the problem

https://codepen.io/ricjonsu098/pen/xxZrvZP?editors=0010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full solution:

```
// create a canvas to work with
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
document.body.appendChild(canvas);

// style canvas
canvas.id     = "canvas";
canvas.width  = 400;
canvas.height = 400;
canvas.setAttribute("style", "border: 1px solid black;");

// get 2D context
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

var squareA = {x:10, y:30, width: 25, height: 25 };
var squareB = {x:10, y:30, width: 25, height: 25 };

// place holders for mouse x,y position
var mouseX = 0;
var mouseY = 0;

var centerX = canvas.width/2;
var centerY = canvas.height/2;


// Render Loop
function update() {
  // update squareA to mouse
  squareA.x = mouseX - (squareB.width * .5);
  squareA.y = mouseY - (squareB.height * .5);

  // update squareB to squareA
  squareB.x = centerX - (squareA.x - centerX);
  squareB.y = centerY - (squareA.y  - centerY);
  
  // clear the canvas
  canvas.width = canvas.width;
  
  // draw first rectangle
  context.fillStyle = "blue";
  context.fillRect (squareA.x,squareA.y,squareA.width,squareA.height);
  
  // draw second rectangle
  context.fillStyle = "green";
  context.fillRect (squareB.x,squareB.y,squareB.width,squareB.height);
  
}

// update mouse position
canvas.onmousemove = function(e) {
  mouseX = e.offsetX;
  mouseY = e.offsetY;
  update();
}
```

Note that I got rid of the interval. You can just update whne the mouse moves.

Comment: hello, what's the difference between this solution than the other one where squareA's position is just subtracted to the canvas size?

Comment: My metal process was to think about reflection through a central point, but mathematically it's the same to subtract As position from the width/height (and that is simpler too).

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps, 400 is canvas size

```js
  // update squareA to mouse
  squareA.x = mouseX;
  squareA.y = mouseY;

  // update squareB to squareA
  squareB.x = 400 - squareA.x;
  squareB.y = 400 - squareA.y;
```